# Custom shape for video preview: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swiftui, swift5

Is it possible to clip a video preview layer like how an image is clipped?

```
    image
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 1))
```

where the video preview layer is from:

```
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 60, width: 335, height: 200)
    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

I've been searching but had no luck. Thanks!

Comment: Have tried `.mask`? 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-mask-one-view-with-another

Comment: .mask works on image type. It doesn’t seem to work on avcapturepreviewlayer or frame or layer. Anything I missed about this modifier?

Comment: Do you have any updates? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Tested on macOS 10.15 Catalina**

The below demo code is targeted for SwiftUI/macOS, but it might be helpful, as only small changes required in code to align it with iOS.

*Note: it is a demo, so code a bit scratchy*

Here is result:

[image: masked video capture from SwiftUI]

Here is demo module code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AppKit
import AVFoundation

class PreviewView: NSView {
    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        var allowedAccess = false
        let blocker = DispatchGroup()
        blocker.enter()
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { flag in
            allowedAccess = flag
            blocker.leave()
        }
        blocker.wait()

        if !allowedAccess {
            print("!!! NO ACCESS TO CAMERA")
            return
        }

        // setup session
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()

        // this part might be different in iOS
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

        guard let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!),
            session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)
            else { return }
        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
        session.commitConfiguration()
        self.captureSession = session

        // instead of below, use layerClass on iOS
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }

    override func viewDidMoveToSuperview() { // on iOS .didMoveToSuperview
        super.viewDidMoveToSuperview()

        if nil != self.superview {
            self.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.captureSession
            self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
            self.captureSession?.startRunning()
        } else {
            self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
        }
    }
}

// for iOS NSView just rename to UIView
struct PreviewHolder: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<PreviewHolder>) -> PreviewView {
        PreviewView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ uiView: PreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<PreviewHolder>) {
    }

    typealias NSViewType = PreviewView
}

struct DemoPreviewLayer: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PreviewHolder()
                .mask(Circle())
        }.frame(width: 400, height: 300)
    }
}

struct DemoPreviewLayer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoPreviewLayer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you want to use this with an external Mac camera instead of the default as per the example it's really quite simple. Just replace AVCaptureDevice.default with the following.

`let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera, .externalUnknown], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)`

And then select the first available device in the resulting list..